# Make use of Safari Website Certificate for OS X Safari Notifications

Tags: macos, safari, pem, safari-push-notifications

I can't figure out how to properly convert my website certificate to a .pem file that I can attach to my attempt to connect to gateway.push.apple.com without getting connection refused when I try to send out notifications.

Answer (score 1):

use the command `openssl x509 -in website_aps_production.cer -inform DER -out apns-cert.pem -outform PEM` in Terminal.